# Convert to Utc give wrong result

Tags: c#, datetime

I am trying to convert my datetime into UTC

```
var date = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(create.StartDate);
```

after conversion   output is  31/1/2018 18:30:00  but what date enters is 
1/2/2018

```
var newdateTimeToUtc = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(Datetime.Now);
```

it shows 1/2/2018 7:12:52 That is correct ? Why would this happens ?

```
var s = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name;
```

zone obtained as `en-IN`

Comment: "zone obtained as en-IN" - that's not a time zone, that's a culture. They're very different things. What does `TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id` return?

Comment: "after conversion output is 31/1/2018 18:30:00 but what date enters is 1/2/2018" - yes, if you're in the Indian time zone then 2018-02-01T00:00:00 local *is* 2018-01-31T18:30:00+05:30. That's not a surprise to me at all. Which value would you expect to be different, and why?

Comment: Is the Timezone of the start date different to your machine’s Timezone? It looks like some sort of adjustment made because you are moving from a Timezone to UTC (also known as Greenwich Mean Time, or the time at 0 degrees longitude which is in London, UK).

Comment: @JonSkeet its "India Standard Time" sir

Comment: Ah, yes, that’ll be it.

Comment: Right. Which is 5:30 ahead of UTC. So midnight at the start of Feb 1st in India is 18:30 on January 31st in UTC. So it's all behaving completely correctly.

Comment: @muszeo: No, UTC isn't "the time in London". *Right now* we happen to be at an offset of UTC+0, but it's not like UTC is "the London time zone". (I'd also advise avoiding using GMT, as it confuses things. Just stick with UTC.)

Comment: Fair enough there’s BST and GMT, yes. But UTC is the non daylight savings adjusted time at 0 degrees which runs through Greenwich, the Greenwich meridian.

Comment: @muszeo: Not always. Between 1968 and 1971, the UK was on standard time of UTC+1. (That was called BST as well, but it was "British Standard Time".) It's entirely feasible that at some point the time zone rules will change again - but the meaning of UTC won't. Therefore it's best not to try to draw a connection between the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your timezone offset is UTC + 05.30. So when you convert your time to UTC, It will deduct 05 hours and 30 minutes from your time. So this is perfectly correct for me.

You can read more information from this [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/converting-between-time-zones) article.